# clojure frequency dictionary from big data

Tags: clojure, functional-programming, stack-overflow, bigdata, word-frequency

I want to write my own naive bayes classifier
I have a file like this:

(This is database of spam and ham messages, first word points to spam or ham, text until eoln is message (size: 0.5 Mb) from here http://www.dt.fee.unicamp.br/~tiago/smsspamcollection/)

```
ham     Go until jurong point, crazy.. Available only in bugis n gre
at world la e buffet... Cine there got amore wat...
ham     Ok lar... Joking wif u oni...
spam    Free entry in 2 a wkly comp to win FA Cup final tkts 21st May 2005. Text FA to 87121 to receive entry question(std txt rate)T&C's apply 08452810075over18's
ham     U dun say so early hor... U c already then say...
ham     Nah I don't think he goes to usf, he lives around here though
spam    FreeMsg Hey there darling it's been 3 week's now and no word back! I'd like some fun you up for it still? Tb ok! XxX std chgs to send, £1.50 to rcv
```

And i want to make a hashmap like this:
{"spam" {"go" 1, "until" 100, ...}, "ham" {......}}
Hash map, where every value is frequency map of words (for ham and spam separatly)

I know, how do it by python or c++, and i made it by clojure, but my solution failed (stackoverflow) in large data

My solution:

```
(defn read_data_from_file [fname]
    (map #(split % #"\s")(map lower-case (with-open [rdr (reader fname)] 
        (doall (line-seq rdr))))))

(defn do-to-map [amap keyseq f]
    (reduce #(assoc %1 %2 (f (%1 %2))) amap keyseq))

(defn dicts_from_data [raw_data]
    (let [data (group-by #(first %) raw_data)]
        (do-to-map
            data (keys data) 
                (fn [x] (frequencies (reduce concat (map #(rest %) x)))))))
```

I've tryed to find where it false and wrote this

```
(def raw_data (read_data_from_file (first args)))
(def d (group-by #(first %) raw_data))
(def f (map frequencies raw_data))
(def d1 (reduce concat (d "spam")))
(println (reduce concat (d "ham")))
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at clojure.lang.Util.runtimeException(Util.java:165)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6476)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6455)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6431)
    at clojure.core$eval.invoke(core.clj:2795)
    at clojure.main$eval_opt.invoke(main.clj:296)
    at clojure.main$initialize.invoke(main.clj:315)
.....
```

Can anyone help me to make this better/effective?
PS Sorry for my writing mistakes. English in not my native language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `apply` instead of `reduce` in the anonymous function avoids the `StackOverflow` exception. Instead of `(fn [x] (frequencies (reduce concat (map #(rest %) x))))` use `(fn [x] (frequencies (apply concat (map #(rest %) x))))`.

The following is the same code a little refactored, but with the exact same logic. The `read-data-from-file` was changed to avoid `map`ping over the sequence of lines twice.

```
(use 'clojure.string)
(use 'clojure.java.io)

(defn read-data-from-file [fname]
  (let [lines (with-open [rdr (reader fname)] 
                (doall (line-seq rdr)))]
    (map #(-> % lower-case (split #"\s")) lines)))

(defn do-to-map [m keyseq f]
    (reduce #(assoc %1 %2 (f (%1 %2))) m keyseq))

(defn process-words [x]
  (->> x 
    (map #(rest %)) 
    (apply concat) ; This is the only real change from the 
                   ; original code, it used to be (reduce concat).
    frequencies))

(defn dicts-from-data [raw_data]
  (let [data (group-by first raw_data)]
    (do-to-map data
               (keys data) 
               process-words)))

(-> "SMSSpamCollection.txt" read-data-from-file dicts-from-data keys)
```

Comment: (-> <data> f1 f2) is equvalent (f1 (f2 data))?

Comment: Actually it is equivalent to `(f2 (f1 data))`, forms are applied from left to right. For more information check out [this](http://blog.fogus.me/2009/09/04/understanding-the-clojure-macro/) post by Fogus. You can also find some examples for the threading macros `->` and `->>`, [here](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/-%3E) and [here](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/-%3E%3E).

Comment: I've mistaken in my first comment. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

One other thing to consider is the use of `(doall (line-seq ...))`,  which reads the entire word list into memory. This could cause problems if the list is very large. A handy trick for accumulating data like this is to use `reduce`. In your case, we need to `reduce` twice: once over the lines, and then over the words in each line. Something like this:

```
(defn parse-line
  [line]
  (str/split (str/lower-case line) #"\s+"))

(defn build-word-freq
  [file]
  (with-open [rdr (io/reader file)]
    (reduce (fn [accum line]
              (let [[spam-or-ham & words] (parse-line line)]
                (reduce #(update-in %1 [spam-or-ham %2] (fnil inc 0)) accum words)))
            {}
            (line-seq rdr))))
```